# How to connect Material-UI to Meteor / React project?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I was trying to connect LeftNav Menu from [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/left-nav) example; however, I got stuck.

Here is the error:

> While building for web.browser:
>    imports/ui/App.jsx:14:2: /imports/ui/App.jsx: Missing class properties transform.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import LeftNav from 'material-ui/lib/left-nav';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';


 // App component - represents the whole app
 export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {open: false};
 }

 handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

 render() {
  return (
    <div>
     <RaisedButton
       label="Toggle LeftNav"
       onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
     />
     <LeftNav open={this.state.open}>
       <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
     </LeftNav>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Is the button displaying properly? Can you reproduce a codepen or something?

Comment: it is not even compile properly on the server side.
`=> Started proxy.
 => Started MongoDB.
 => Errors prevented startup:

   While building for web.browser:
   imports/ui/App.jsx:16:2: /imports/ui/App.jsx: Missing class properties transform.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (and if I were you, I'd install the beta of material-ui via `npm install --save material-ui@next`).

```
import React from 'react';
import { LeftNav, MenuItem, RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';

// App component - represents the whole app
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
    this.state = { open: false };
  }

  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Toggle LeftNav"
          onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
        />
        <LeftNav open={this.state.open}>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
        </LeftNav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I just updated to the beta version of material-ui

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using `stage-1` features of the ECMAScript specification. you have to install the proper plugins in your compiler.

Here are some instructions on how to install the plugin for Babel.

(1) At your project folder in terminal, use the following command to install `babel-preset-stage-1`

```
meteor npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-1
```

(2) Then go to `.bablerc` file in your project folder (create it if you don't have one) and update the presets array as per the following **order matters**,

```
"presets": ["env", "react",  "stage-1"]
```

Try again & let me know if you still have a problem.